# Expose my java /C ++ library apis to javascript

Tags: android

I want expose my Android library APIs to javascript. Is there anyway to achieve it.

I dont want to use webview for this.

Thanks
kishore

Comment: Javascript runs within a browser and is NOTHING like java they are not compatible in that way... that being said you could potentially use Applet as a means to communicate with the server that has your API on classpath.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but here i want to use for android sdks so its not a complete web application...